# Problems with web archive files cannot be opened

Tags: finder, notes.app

I've saved several webpages as web archive files and put them in various Apple Notes. I just tried to open one and got

> cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

So I started trying to open more of them and was able to open a couple, but most got the error above and a few got this error

> `filename` is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash

That doesn't give me much confidence in this format and/or macOS's ability to preserve and open them. The reason I save them is so I don't have to rely on the site remaining available.

Any ideas why this is happening? How can I prevent it? I can't figure out any rhyme or reason to why this is happening, especially since most of the web archive files are months and months old, and in that time I've upgraded to Catalina, so who knows.

Comment: Can you right click and hit open ? Or run `open abc.webarchive` ?  (yes it's Catalina causing the trouble !)

Comment: @ankii for the ones that say they cannot be opened, yes I can actually open them by right-clicking, but I don't want to do that. You say it's Catalina causing problems, but why can I open some of these web archive files that I created before upgrading, but not others?

Comment: I think it's the quarantine bit set on older files. Try using xattr to remove it. (such questions are both here & on stackoverflow)